# The nonexistence of a polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm studying algebraic geometry. To illustrate a nonalgebraic set, it is given that a unit circle except for a point on it in cartesian product or whole plane except for one point. Why doesn't a polynomial whose zeros are a unit circle except for a point or  whole plane except for one point exist? I'll be glad if one explains this situation.

Comment: Are you working over $\mathbb{C}$ or some arbitrary $\bar{k}$?

Comment: I am working over arbitrary $K$.

Answer (score 3):

Polynomials are continuous functions. A function that is identically zero on the plane except at one point is not continuous. The same goes for the unit circle.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much Joel.

Comment: I am glad I could help :)